# Combine multiple fields with condition

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have multiple MS Access fields and I need to combine most of them with a condition. I'm still a beginner with complicated SQL queries thus the limitation to translate the following pseudocode into reality:

```
SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3
CREATE new_field

// these would be WHERE-queries
if field_1 & field_2 are "missing", "unknown" or empty
    then new_field = field_3 

else if field_2 & field_3 are "missing", "unknown" or empty
    then new_field = field_1

else if field_1 & field_3 are "missing", "unknown" or empty
    then new_field = field_2
```

The `new_field` will basically contain the values of combined `field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3` ... `field_n`. Assume that only one of these n-fields have a legit value.

Is this achievable in MS Access using a simple query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will be running the query within an Access session you can use `Nz`.  This will return the value of the field which contains a non-Null value ...

```sql
SELECT Nz(field_1, '') & Nz(field_2, '') & Nz(field_3, '') AS combined
```

If you need a query which can work from outside an Access session, `Nz` is not available.  Use an `IIf` expression instead.

```sql
SELECT
      IIf(field_1 Is Null, '', field_1)
    & IIf(field_2 Is Null, '', field_2)
    & IIf(field_3 Is Null, '', field_3)
```

Comment: It works perfectly! 
For the other users, just a reminder to add `FROM table_name` at the end or it will just ask for the fields' values and concatenate them.

Comment: How do I filter custom values such as "missing" and "unknown"? I tried adding them in the second query after `'',` but Access declared it as "wrong number of arguments".