# Combine Access fields into one field given two queries

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have *n* MS Access fields that needs checking per row for **one** legal cell. A legal cell simply does not have the values "missing", "unknown"; or is not blank. All of these cells will be combined into a single field that only contains cell with legal values.

Referring to the table below,

[image: coven]

`Name_Final` will contain these legal cells from `Name_2010`, `Name_2011` and `Name_2012`.

I already have two separate queries to help me do the job but I need to combine their results in order for me to get the `Name_Final` field.

1. **[Query that returns non-null or non-empty cells](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19251799/1685185)**

   ```
    SELECT 
        Nz(Name_2010, '') & 
        Nz(Name_2011, '') & 
        Nz(Name_2012, '') 
        AS Name_Final
   ```

and the result is:

[image: coven-query-1]

2. **Filter cells with undesired values**

   ```
    SELECT 
        Name_2010 Not In ('missing', 'unknown', 'Blank(s)', ' ', Nz), 
        Name_2011 Not In ('missing', 'unknown', 'Blank(s)', ' ', Nz), 
        Name_2012 Not In ('missing', 'unknown', 'Blank(s)', ' ', Nz) 
        AS Name_Final
        FROM Table1;
   ```

This one returns `0`, `-1` or blank for values indicated in the `NOT IN` parenthesis, values not indicated in the `NOT IN` parenthesis` or for blank values respectively.

Its output is:

[image: coven-query-2]

**I need to find a way to integrate these two sets of queries together to come up with `Name_Final`.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT IIf(Name_2010 In (Null, 'missing', 'unknown', 'Blank(s)', ' '), '', Name_2010) &
   IIf(Name_2011 In (Null, 'missing', 'unknown', 'Blank(s)', ' '), '', Name_2011) &
   IIf(Name_2012 In (Null, 'missing', 'unknown', 'Blank(s)', ' '), '', Name_2012) 
   AS Name_Final
FROM Table1;
```

That said, I would be inclined to just clean up the data and replace all 'missing', 'unknown' or 'Blanks(s)' values with NULL, which would allow replacing the IIf's with simple Nz's -

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Name_2010 = Null WHERE Trim(Name_2010) In ('missing', 'unknown', 'Blank(s)', '');
UPDATE Table1 SET Name_2011 = Null WHERE Trim(Name_2011) In ('missing', 'unknown', 'Blank(s)', '');
UPDATE Table1 SET Name_2012 = Null WHERE Trim(Name_2012) In ('missing', 'unknown', 'Blank(s)', '');
```