# Remove redundant Access field cells

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Continued from **[Combine Access fields into one field given two queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19333877/1685185)**

I have the table below with three main fields `Name_2010`, `Name_2011` and `Name_2012` and they need to be integrated as `Name_Final`.

[image: coven]

I used the query below to select only a particular member of the three fields per row but currently it does not work as intended as it does not recognize redundant cells.

```
SELECT
  IIf(Name_2010 In (Name_2011, Name_2012), '', Name_2010) 
  AS N1,
  IIf(Name_2011 In (Name_2010, Name_2012), '', Name_2011) 
  AS N2,
  IIf(Name_2012 In (Name_2010, Name_2011), '', Name_2012) 
  AS N3
  FROM Table1;
```

**What query should I use to achieve `Name_Final` given my current table?**

Comment: Will you be adding fields to `Table1` over time: `Name_2013`; `Name_2014`; and so forth?

Comment: Yes sir. So far I have only these non-recursive queries to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, N1 &
  IIf(N2 <> N1, N2, '') &
  IIf((N3 <> N2) And (N3 <> N1), N3, '') AS Name_Final
FROM
  (SELECT ID, Nz(Name_2010) AS N1, Nz(Name_2011) AS N2, Nz(Name_2012) AS N3
   FROM Table1) AS T
ORDER BY ID;
```

The `ORDER BY` clause is for what it says, rather than being a part of the 'Name_Final' calculation.