# Dynamic SQL column value duplicate and difference detection merge query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have *n*-columns that may contain **unique** or **duplicated** values meaning each column may have different values or the same ones.

What I want to achieve is an MS Access script that can analyze *n*-columns that could do the following:

- [**If the columns if only *one* has a value and the rest are blank** then the final value will be the only one seen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19334442/1685185) (**Note**: this one is already accomplished).

  ```
  +-----+----+----+-----+
  |Var1 |Var2|Var3|Final|
  +-----+----+----+-----+
  |1    |    |    |1    |
  +-----+----+----+-----+
  |     |    |3   |3    |
  +-----+----+----+-----+
  |     |yes |    |yes  |
  +-----+----+----+-----+
  ```
- **If there are more than one different values** then ask the user to choose between these values (**Update**: precedence of variables instead of user selection ie. `Var1` > `Var2` > ... > `VarN`).

  ```
  +----+----+----+-----+
  |Var1|Var2|Var3|Final|
  +----+----+----+-----+
  |1   |3   |    |?    |
  +----+----+----+-----+
  |ok  |    |3   |?    |
  +----+----+----+-----+
  |    |yes |5   |?    |
  +----+----+----+-----+
  ```
- **If there are more than one same values** then proceed to use that as the final value.

  ```
  +----+----+----+-----+
  |Var1|Var2|Var3|Final|
  +----+----+----+-----+
  |1   |1   |    |1    |
  +----+----+----+-----+
  |ok  |    |ok  |ok   |
  +----+----+----+-----+
  |    |yes |yes |yes  |
  +----+----+----+-----+
  ```

Comment: The second bullet point is not practical with just Access SQL.  Consider a form to present the choices, accept the user's selection and store it.

Comment: @HansUp: is it possible to specify a certain column's values to be used in case of #2 (say between Var1 and Var2, Var1's is going to be used)?

Comment: I said not *practical*.  I'm not ready to claim it's *impossible*, but I wouldn't invest my time exploring that route.

Comment: Thank you for the immediate response! I'll think of another way to get around the data's nature.

Comment: If this is a periodic data transformation task, consider a VBA procedure  for the first and third bullet points, and a form to manage the second bullet point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Solve all three situations, the code below takes care of precedence, empty and possible null values in the content. `INTO temp` will save the query result into a table named `temp`.

   ```
   SELECT id, var1, var2, 
       IIf(Len(var1 & "") = 0, var2, var1) AS merged
   INTO temp
   FROM myTable;
   ```
2. Transfer the records into the source table.

   ```
   UPDATE myTable 
       INNER JOIN temp 
         ON [myTable].ID=temp.ID 
   SET myTable.merged= [temp].[merged];
   ```

The question "[*Combine values from n-fields with precedence*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21127024/3119058)" helped!

Answer (score 1):

On reviewing the answers to your previous questions on this topic they seem to rely pretty heavily on `IIf(Var1 <> Var2, ...` constructs. If you *really* want an n-column solution for *n* of any non-trivial size the first thing you need to do is convert your columns into rows. For sample data [Table1]:

```
RowID  Var1  Var2  Var3  Final
-----  ----  ----  ----  -----
    1  1                      
    2              3          
    3        yes              
    4  1     3                
    5  ok          3          
    6        yes   5          
    7  1     1                
    8  ok          ok         
    9        yes   yes
```

Create a saved query in Access named [Unpivoted]:

```sql
SELECT RowID, "Var1" AS var, Var1 AS val FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT RowID, "Var2" AS var, Var2 AS val FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT RowID, "Var3" AS var, Var3 AS val FROM Table1
```

That query returns the following, and will be the basis from which we work:

```
RowID  var   val
-----  ----  ---
    1  Var1  1  
    2  Var1     
    3  Var1     
    4  Var1  1  
    5  Var1  ok 
    6  Var1     
    7  Var1  1  
    8  Var1  ok 
    9  Var1     
    1  Var2     
    2  Var2     
    3  Var2  yes
    4  Var2  3  
    5  Var2     
    6  Var2  yes
    7  Var2  1  
    8  Var2     
    9  Var2  yes
    1  Var3     
    2  Var3  3  
    3  Var3     
    4  Var3     
    5  Var3  3  
    6  Var3  5  
    7  Var3     
    8  Var3  ok 
    9  Var3  yes
```

Our first step will be to pull out the values where RowID has just one distinct non-Null value. We'll save this query as [NoSelectionRequired]

```sql
SELECT RowID, First(val) AS FirstOfval
FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT RowID, val
        FROM Unpivoted
        WHERE val IS NOT NULL
    )
GROUP BY RowID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

That returns

```
RowID  FirstOfval
-----  ----------
    1  1         
    2  3         
    3  yes       
    7  1         
    8  ok        
    9  yes
```

So we can cover Cases 1 and 3 with the following query *(see also Edit1, below)*

```sql
UPDATE Table1 SET Final = DLookup("FirstOfval", "NoSelectionRequired", "RowID=" & RowID)
```

After we run that query [Table1] now looks like this:

```
RowID  Var1  Var2  Var3  Final
-----  ----  ----  ----  -----
    1  1                 1    
    2              3     3    
    3        yes         yes  
    4  1     3                
    5  ok          3          
    6        yes   5          
    7  1     1           1    
    8  ok          ok    ok   
    9        yes   yes   yes
```

Now... for Case 2:

You need to provide a mechanism for the users to pick the values they want. One way you could do that would be to use a [Selections] table...

[image: SelectionsTable.png]

...that you could populate with a statement like this

```sql
INSERT INTO Selections ([RowID], [Value])
SELECT RowID, val 
FROM Unpivoted
WHERE val IS NOT NULL
    AND RowID IN
        (
            SELECT RowID FROM
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT RowID, val
                    FROM Unpivoted
                    WHERE val IS NOT NULL
                )
            GROUP BY RowID
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        )
ORDER BY RowID, val
```

so your [Selections] table contains

```
RowID  Value  Selected
-----  -----  --------
    4  1      False   
    4  3      False   
    5  3      False   
    5  ok     False   
    6  5      False   
    6  yes    False
```

Slap that into a continuous form with checkboxes for the [Selected] field and a bit of logic behind it to only allow one selection per RowID, then once the user has made their choices:

```
RowID  Value  Selected
-----  -----  --------
    4  1      True    
    4  3      False   
    5  3      True   
    5  ok     False    
    6  5      False   
    6  yes    True
```

then you can update the remaining rows in [Table1] *(see also Edit1, below)*

```sql
UPDATE Table1 SET Final = DLookup("Value","Selections","RowID=" & RowID & " AND Selected")
WHERE RowID IN (SELECT RowID FROM Selections)
```

and there you have it:

```
RowID  Var1  Var2  Var3  Final
-----  ----  ----  ----  -----
    1  1                 1    
    2              3     3    
    3        yes         yes  
    4  1     3           1    
    5  ok          3     3    
    6        yes   5     yes  
    7  1     1           1    
    8  ok          ok    ok   
    9        yes   yes   yes
```

### Edit1 - re: comment

For larger datasets the two queries that write the results to the [Final] column may take a long time to run because they are not terribly efficient. In that case the solution would be to dump the results to a temporary table and then use that to update the main table.

For the first update (Cases 1 and 3), instead of doing

```sql
UPDATE Table1 SET Final = DLookup("FirstOfval", "NoSelectionRequired", "RowID=" & RowID)
```

we would do...

```sql
SELECT * INTO zzzTemp
FROM NoSelectionRequired
```

...followed by...

```sql
UPDATE 
    Table1 
    INNER JOIN 
    zzzTemp 
        ON Table1.RowID = zzzTemp.RowID 
SET Table1.Final = [zzzTemp].[FirstOfval]
```

For the second update (Case 2), instead of doing

```sql
UPDATE Table1 SET Final = DLookup("Value","Selections","RowID=" & RowID & " AND Selected")
WHERE RowID IN (SELECT RowID FROM Selections)
```

we would do...

```sql
SELECT * INTO zzzTemp
FROM Selections
WHERE Selected
```

...followed by...

```sql
UPDATE 
    Table1 
    INNER JOIN 
    zzzTemp 
        ON Table1.RowID = zzzTemp.RowID 
SET Table1.Final = [zzzTemp].[Value]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Unfortunately I am stuck in the step before the Case 2 solution. The query is taking too long and it's been up for an hour and still not stopping. I have 3 columns and 65000 rows. Is this a hardware limitation in my part?