# Merge rows code returns empty content

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am merging two columns in the same table. I am following the [answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20166118/1685185).

I have a table that looks like this and the `var` as the merged variable (it has an `id` but not included here):

```
var1    var2    var
1               1
        2       2
8               8    
        10      10
```

I use the code below to get all values for the concerned columns which works perfectly. The two concerned columns are combined into one with their respective values.

```
# code1
SELECT ID, "var1" AS var, var1 AS val FROM source
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, "var2" AS var, var2 AS val FROM source
```

Next is I need to get the unique values per row and column combination:

```
# code2
SELECT ID, First(val) AS FirstOfVal
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, val
    FROM code1
    WHERE val IS NOT NULL
  )
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

In `code2` I expect to get a table with a `FirstOfVal` column filled with values but no contents in my case.

How do I solve this?

I tried using it on other combinations of columns and it worked perfectly *except* for this column that I'm modifying. The only difference I can think of these columns I'm having a problem merging is that they contain a lot of empty rows (as seen above) and each column has its own value, no two rows' columns have both values.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `FIRST()`. You should be getting an error from code2.

Comment: Sorry! It's actually SQL in MS Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally solved it!

Here are the steps for this special case:

1. `SELECT` the `id` and the desired columns. Note that this expects the columns to both *not* contain values (I haven't tested it with both columns containing a value, whether the same or not).

   ```
   # query1
   SELECT id, col1 & col2 AS merged
   FROM table_name;
   ```
2. Insert the results of the query before into a temporary table for security (better save it that encounter errors).

   ```
   # query2
   SELECT * INTO temp
   FROM query1
   WHERE FirstOfVal;
   ```
3. Insert the contents of the temporary table into the main table.

   ```
   UPDATE table_name
       INNER JOIN temp ON table_name.id = temp.id
       SET table_name.merged = [temp].[merged];
   ```

You now have the merged columns into your source table.