# Combine values from n-fields with precedence

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an example table below:

```
+----+----+------+
|var1|var2|merged|
+----+----+------+
|a   |b   |a     |
+----+----+------+
|    |c   |c     |
+----+----+------+
|    |x   |x     |
+----+----+------+
|c   |d   |c     |
+----+----+------+
```

I want to merge `var1` and `var2`'s values with the rule that whenever `var1` has a value, it should be picked over `var2`.

---

My code below does not achieve it and I am at a loss on how to implement this.

```
SELECT id, var1 & var2 AS merged
FROM myTable
```

All this code does is concatenated `var1` and `var2`'s data which is not I want. The [one I asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852938/merge-rows-code-returns-empty-content) is not working as desired anymore.

```
+----+----+------+
|var1|var2|merged|
+----+----+------+
|a   |b   |ab    |
+----+----+------+
|    |c   |c     |
+----+----+------+
|    |x   |x     |
+----+----+------+
|c   |d   |cd    |
+----+----+------+
```

---

The one below from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164319/dynamic-access-column-value-duplication-and-difference-script) question does not take into account lone values :(

```
SELECT ID, var1, var2, 
  SWITCH (        
    var1 IS NOT NULL, var1,     
    var2 IS NOT NULL, var2,   
  ) AS merged
FROM myTable;
```

```
+----+----+------+
|var1|var2|merged|
+----+----+------+
|a   |b   |a     |
+----+----+------+
|    |c   |      |
+----+----+------+
|    |x   |      |
+----+----+------+
|c   |d   |c     |
+----+----+------+
```

---

#### UPDATE

After using the methods provided in the answers, I have seen *some* of my records achieve what I presented in the first table above. But after looking through the other rows I managed to find ones that were skipped, as presented in the third table.

Below is the code I use and screenshots of the results.

```
SELECT ID, var1, var2, 

      # method 1
      SWITCH (        
        var1 IS NOT NULL, var1,     
        var2 IS NOT NULL, var2
      ) AS switchResult,

      # method 2
      Nz(var1, var2) AS NzResult,

      # method 3
      Iif(var1 IS NULL, var2, var1) AS IifResult

FROM myTable;
```

The results here are what I wanted:

> Note: `ID`, `var1`, `var2`, `switchResult`, `NzResult`, `IifResult`
> are the column names for guide

[image]

But as I search for `(Blanks)` there appears to be failed rows:

[image]

It seems that `var1`'s values if `var2`'s missing return correct queries but when `var2` does have a value and `var1` does not, some rows do not return correct queries.

Does anyone know why this happens? I already checked if `var1` and `var2` contains whitespace and they do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `var1` when it is not Null, and otherwise you want `var2`.  You can use `Nz` to get that.

```sql
SELECT var1, var2, Nz(var1, var2) AS  merged
FROM myTable;
```

If you will be running the query from outside an Access session, the `Nz` function will not be available.  In that case, you can use an `IIf` expression.

```sql
SELECT var1, var2, IIf(var1 Is Null, var2, var1) AS  merged
FROM myTable;
```

If `var1` may contain zero-length strings (`""`), and you want those treated the same as Null --- meaning return `var2` in that situation --- use this query ...

```sql
SELECT var1, var2, IIf(Len(var1 & "") = 0, var2, var1) AS  merged
FROM myTable;
```

Comment: Hello again! I just found out that _some_ of my records' `var2` values are not put in the `merge` field even though `var1` is empty (no whitespace too). Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Does the table design all zero-length strings in `var1`?  Check the table in Design View ... the property is called *Allow Zero Length* in the General tab of the lower panel.

Comment: Yes, `var1`'s _Allow Zero Length_ is set to _Yes_.

Comment: Does this query return any rows? `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Len(var1) = 0;`  If so, are those the same rows which don't give what you expect in the merge field?

Comment: Yes, it returns rows and these are the same rows with the problem. Do I have to redo my database?

Comment: No, you don't have to; I'll revise the answer to cope with zero-lenth strings in `var1`.  But I believe it is bad design to permit both Null and zero-length strings in a text field.  Permit one only; not both.  Allowing both leads to the type of confusion we're dealing with now.

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually just imported a CSV and never thought of this occurrence. I'll take note of it in the future.

Comment: OK, after importing the CSV, you can substitute Null for zero-length strings in `var1` ... `UPDATE myTable SET var1 = Null WHERE Len(var1) = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT var1, var2, COALESCE(var1, var2) AS merged
  FROM myTable;
```

Comment: It should work, I don't know if in all versions ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249645.aspx))

Comment: I see, something (apparently) new in Access 2013. Thanks for the tip! +1